# Pass Appium driver instance from one class to another

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am automating an android app and have capabilities method in setup class file and returning driver instance from that method.

I have one class file for one of my pages where I am calling that capabilities method and using driver instance to locating elements, although I am not able to use that driver instance in other class file. what will be best approach to do that?

Comment: I have implemented it using solution provided by Mohammad and this question can be closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done with OOP.
You should define a main class for creating a driver instance and define creating a driver instance in it. Then inherit other classes from the main class.
Assuming we call it `MainClass`. Then we should automate two sections of our app like `Register` and `Login`. It should implement like this: (Python)

**MainClass.py**

```py
from appium import webdriver


class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver_instance = None

    def open_application(self, udid=None):
        caps = {
            'platformName': 'Android', 'deviceName': Galaxy A7, 'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
            'skipServerInstallation': True, 'appActivity': 'YOUR_APP_START_ACTIVITY', 'noReset': no_reset,
            'udid': udid, 'newCommandTimeout': 1200, 'autoGrantPermissions': True,
            'appPackage': 'YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME'}
        driver = webdriver.Remote(str(appium_server), caps)
        self.driver_instance = driver
        return driver
```

**MyApplication.py**

```py
from MainClass import MainClass


class MyApplication(MainClass)
        def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def open_my_application(udid=None):
        self.open_application()
```

**Authenticate.py**

```py
from MainClass import MainClass


class Authenticate(MainClass)
        def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def login(self, username, password):
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//input[1]").set_text(username)
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//input[2]").set_text(password)
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text='Submit']").click()

    def register(self, username, password, name, phone):
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//input[1]").set_text(username)
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//input[2]").set_text(password)
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//input[3]").set_text(name)
        self.driver_instance.find_element_by_xpath("//input[4]").set_text(phone)
```

**Test.py**

```py
import MyApplication
import Authenticate

MyApplication().open_my_application(udid="5c1425bd54c88")
Authenticate().login('user12', 'user12-password')
```

1- As you can see in the above example, firstly we create `MainClass` and include creating driver instance keyword which we called `open_application()` here, it will create the instance and store driver instance variables as `self.driver_instance` variable.

2- Then we create another class named `MyApplication` that inherits from `MainClass`. Then we define a function called `open_my_application()` that will call the `open_application()` from `MainClass` as instance (class object). So the `self.driver_instance` will store as `MainClass`'s variable and you can create any class inherited from `MainClass` as much as you want.

3- We create a class named `Authenticate` to do login and register.

4- Test.py is a sample test file finally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, it will help, I will try to implement it this way. although stackoverflow not allowing me to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do create a proper test framework for object handling which will be very simple to update .For complete framework refer this video-https://youtu.be/cHOs-CmY-M8